# JobRepositoryTestUtils required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing SpringBoot/Spring batch application which interacts with mongodb, the implemntation is done and its working in normal way(via scheduled job launcher) but when i unit test my job it throwing

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Can someone will help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could u update the question with application properties and describe more about it.

Comment: The error message indicates that you do not provide a `DataSource` bean in your test. If you want to use an embedded database you can do so e.g. with the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for the response , i resolved by adding new Datasource() definition into my config class....